# Having issue to create navigation between screen

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-ios

I have a splash screen which goes to the Intro page after a few seconds and from the Intro page, I have a link for sign in and sign up. I tried to set up navigation from the Intro page to/from Login but encounter an error which says: 
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate').

I have tried to check the documentation on react-navigation but not clear with the explanation as they muddled up all screens in App.js.

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, StatusBar, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Intro from './screen/Intro';
import Login from './components/Login';


const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    IntroScreen: Intro,
    LoginScreen: Login,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'IntroScreen',
  }
);

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(RootStack);
export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar
         barStyle="light-content"
         backgroundColor="#fefefe"
        />
      <Intro/>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Intro.js
The page follows the splash screen display and from the page I can select login or sign up.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
Text, 
Image,
View, 
ImageBackground,
StyleSheet,
TouchableOpacity
  } 
from 'react-native';

import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
export default class Intro extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        SplashScreen.hide();
      }
    render(){
        return(
            <ImageBackground  source={require('../images/signup-background.jpg')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                 <Image 
                  source ={ require('../images/logo.png')}
                 />
                 <Text style={styles.simpleText}>WELCOME</Text>
                 <Text style={styles.literal}>Thank you for your interest in the APG app. </Text>
                 <Text style={styles.literal}>How can we help you?</Text>
                 <TouchableOpacity
                  style= {styles.signinCont}
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('IntroScreen')} 
                  >
                    <Text style= {styles.signinText}>
                        I am already an APG Patient
                    </Text>
                 </TouchableOpacity>
                 <TouchableOpacity style= {styles.signupCont}>
                    <Text style= {styles.signupText}>
                        I am not an APG Patient 
                    </Text>
                 </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        );

    }
}
```

Login.js
On the Login, I have a button to link to Signup and forgot password in case the user doesn't have an account

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
 Text, 
 TouchableOpacity,
 Label,
 View,
 TextInput,
 StyleSheet,

 } 
 from 'react-native';


 export default class Login extends Component {
     render(){
         return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View>
                    <Text>Login</Text>
                </View>
                <Label>Email</Label>
                <TextInput 
                  style={Styles.textbox}  
                  placeholder="Email"
                  value= {this.state.email}

                />
                <Label>Password</Label>
                <TextInput 
                  style={Styles.textbox}  
                  placeholder="Password"
                  value ={this.state.password}
                  secureTextEntry={true}
                />
                <View>
                    <Text>Forgot password</Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.signin}>
                    <Text style ={styles.signinText}>Sign In</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View>
                    <Text>Not an APG Member? </Text>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.signup}
                 onPress ={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp') }
                 >
                    <Text>Sign Up</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
         );
     }
 }
```

I want to be able to choose either the login or signup as the case may be from the Intro.js and on login.js to be able to click on signup for registration and from signup to be able to click login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

`onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')}` do not invoke `this.props.navigation.navigate` function.

Change your `onPress` property as below.

Use es6 arrow function for making anonymous function.

```js
<TouchableOpacity 
    style={styles.signup}
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')}
>
```

or you can reference your function in `onPress`.  It makes performance better when render again.

```js
navigate = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')
}

return (
...
<TouchableOpacity 
    style={styles.signup}
    onPress={this.navigate}
>
)
```

## Why

`props` only references value even if it is function. So make `props` reference anonymous function or funtion in class you predefined.

And do not forget `bind(this)` when you use not arrow function.

```js
navigate() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')
}

...
onPress={this.navigate.bind(this)}
...
```

Comment: It is still giving the same error "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Comment: I have fixed. I think I have a problem with the styling